# JavaFX 2.2: how to bind String to Integer?

Tags: java, javafx, binding, javafx-2

I'm trying the following code but it doesn't compile:

```
SimpleIntegerProperty startPageProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

TextField startPageField = new TextField();

Bindings.bindBidirectional(
    startPageField.textProperty(), startPageProperty, new IntegerStringConverter()
);
```

The last static method call does not accept these parameters.

Comment: could you provide the compiler error ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Bindings#bindBidirectional` expects a `StringConverter[Number]`, you are providing a `StringConverter[Integer]`. Though it may not be intuitive, you'll have to use a [`NumberStringConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/util/converter/NumberStringConverter.html) instead.

```
Bindings.bindBidirectional(startPageField.textProperty(), 
                           startPageProperty, 
                           new NumberStringConverter());
```

Answer (score 1):

While the previous answer is correct, there is another way to solve this, which works better if you want to format numbers in a specific way (e.g. with thousands separators):

```
var formatter = new TextFormatter<>(new NumberStringConverter("#,###"));
formatter.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(startPageProperty);
startPageField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
```

The advantage of using a `TextFormatter` is that it will reformat any number entered by the user when the text field loses focus.